# How to make this kind of typography in blender

Tags: modeling

[image]

How to create model with this type of typography in blender? I tried using single vertex to make the curve and then fill it until it become a flat plane. I extrude the plane and add subdivision modifier but the result ain't smooth.

Comment: Apart from @Nathan's answer below, you might find Joey Carlino's [Text in geometry nodes](https://youtu.be/_7GLcKJbWDw) tutorial suitable.

Comment: Intranetgirl has a good tutorial on this

Comment: Why don't you just sculpt the letters? A few Metaballs and vertices with a skin modifier, then remesh, smooth, etc

Comment: @Blunder: maybe she wants to animate them with trim... ;)

Answer (score 7):

Blender's curves don't support branching (not without some really extreme difficulty) so I don't think we want to use curve objects to do this.  Instead, we can use a skin modifier to make these kind of branching letters:

[image]

I start with geometry that is just a string of verts (pictured on the right), give that string a single level of subdivision to smooth/curve it a bit, then give it a skin modifier to create the geometry.  Then I can tune the radius of each vertex in edit mode to eye, using ctrl a.  A final subdivision modifier adds additional geometry after the skin to smooth everything out nicely.